# Detecting headset with Corebluetooth framework

Tags: iphone, ios, uuid, core-bluetooth, headset

I have bluetooth headset 4.0 LE. I want to connect that device with corebluetooth framework. Can anyone tell me what will the UUID for the same.  Currently i am not able to detect the headset. I have check UUID 180A (broadcast profile), 1108 (headset). But not working for me.

Comment: Your headset may be Bluetooth, but probably not Bluetooth LE. LE doesn't have enough bandwidth to convey audio, so you're not going to be able to use Core Bluetooth to contact it.

Comment: but is is Bluetooth 4.0 and it is also LE. Because bluetooth LE is a features of Bluetooth 4.0.

Comment: No, it's not, and this is part of the confusion around that standard. The regular, full-power Bluetooth is different from LE. Devices can support both, but they must be explicitly dual-mode in nature. In the case of your headset, I doubt it is. Even if it is, it won't have the audio over the LE portion, just maybe playback or volume controls.

Comment: The Low-Energy part of the Bluetooth 4.0 is like a fork from the classical Bluetooth...
And I suggest that if you need to debug a new BLE device, do not search for special UUID, read all that you can, and filter, after...

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth 4.0 is the latest standard in that connectivity. However you need to know that Bluetooth LE is conforms to Bluetooth 4.0 standards but does not have complete data transfer capabilities. Bluetooth LE was specifically made to suit certain devices that need to be ON for long periods but do not transmit heavy amount of data. Example heart rate monitors passing a simple int value every 1 second.

Generally  BTLE devices are less than 20gms in weight and can last 6-8 months on a fresh battery.

You cant expect data transfer capabilities to consume such ultra low power. So a headset could be Bluetooth 4.0 ready but it is not a Bluetooth LE device; and Corebluetooth framework only applies to BTLE devices